# How do I hide the borders around checkboxes in an ASP.Net CheckBoxList control with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I need to get rid of the borders around the individual checkboxes that are rendered by a CheckBox control. Here's what it looks like now:

[image: Image with checkbox borders]

The ASP.Net markup is straightforward:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblEthnicity" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
  RepeatColumns="3" RepeatLayout="Table" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

which is in a cell in a table with the class `formTable` applied (see below).

As you can see, I've tried setting the attributes `BorderStyle="None"` and `BorderWidth="0"` to no effect.

I'm pretty sure that what's behind this is the following CSS, which puts rounded corner borders around the enclosing table cells, which I want to keep:

```
.formTable
{
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: solid 1px #bbbbbb;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.formTable tr, .formTable tr td, .formTable tr th
{
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #bbbbbb;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

I added the following CSS, which also did nothing:

```
.formTable tr td input[type="checkbox"]
{
  border: none;
}
```

Finally, the HTML rendered from the .aspx for the CheckBoxList, as seen in Chrome DevTools, looks like this (edited a little for brevity):

```
<table id="main_cblEthnicity" style="border-width:0px; border-style:None; border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;">
        <input id="main_cblEthnicity_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$main$cblEthnicity$0"
          checked="checked" value="Native American" />
        <label for="main_cblEthnicity_0">Native American</label>
      </td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any suggestions on how I can get rid of the unwanted borders?

**UPDATE**: Here are some images to make it more clear what's going on and what I'm trying to accomplish:

This is what I'm getting now:

[image: Incorrect - borders around individual checkbox cells]

This is what I get if I use either suggestion that has been presented so far:

[image: Incorrect - no borders around the table cells]

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Correct - borders around the table cells, but not around the checkboxes within]

In addition to the suggestions made here, I tried adding this to the CSS, but it made no difference:

```
.formTable tr td > input[type="checkbox"] {
  border: none;
}
```

I also tried this in Javascript/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formTable tr td > input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr("border");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can u post a fiddle of the problem? Also - which browser is this happening in?

Comment: you cannot remove native browser checkbox border. Implement your own customized element

Comment: @A.Wolff that's not what I'm trying to do; I'm trying to remove the table cell border around the individual checkboxes.

Comment: @Yuriy I'll see if I can; it will be difficult since this is ASP.Net-generated HTML I'm dealing with. It doesn't matter which browser I use, I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the `input` but in it's `td`. 
Look:

```
<td style="border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;">
```

Here (above) is defined the border radius. And here (below) the border color:

```
.formTable tr, .formTable tr td, .formTable tr th
{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid 1px #bbbbbb;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

So, to change this, you may want to add just after the above CSS code, this:

```
.formTable tr td
{
    border:0;
}
```

Doing this, you'll just make the `td` borders to disappear and not the borders of `tr` or `th`

### UPDATE AFTER OP's CLARIFICATIONS

Oh, all right. Now with those new screenshots we can see well what you're tryning to do achieve.
Anyway, you're still trying to remove a border from the input, but I repeat, the problem *isn't* the input but it's td.

I'll explain you with the code you gave us ok? So:

```
<table id="main_cblEthnicity" style="border-width:0px; border-style:None; border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;">
        <input id="main_cblEthnicity_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$main$cblEthnicity$0"
          checked="checked" value="Native American" />
        <label for="main_cblEthnicity_0">Native American</label>
      </td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the HTML code of the **table that has inside all those checkboxes**. All it's TDs have rounded borders and stuff we already know.  This **table that has inside all those checkboxes** is inside a bigger TD (which borders you want to keep) W're in the following situation:

[image: Table TDs]

So now you got 2 ways to act without changing all your HTML: CSS or jQuery.

### The CSS way

Pretty simple, you may want to put inline style at those table cells (which have checkboxes inside) like this: `style="border:0"` instead of `style="border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;"`. Or Just create a new CSS class like this

```
.no-borders {
    border:0;
}
```

and apply it on every td you don't want to see.

### The jQuery way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formTable input[type="checkbox"]').parent().css('border','none');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: ya, exactly my thought. Even I guess OP is talking about the checkbox element border

Comment: Except that, just like Yuriy's answer, this gets rid of the border around the table cells, which I want to keep; I just want to get rid of the one around the individual checkbox cells (ASP.Net renders the CheckBoxList as a table). If I change the CheckBoxList's rendering mode to Flow, it just looks bad.

Comment: @timbck2: I've seen that you may have resolved your problems with Wolff in comments below only after my update. Anyway, if you want, I explained you why the problem was the TD and not the INPUT. Just read because it'll be useful for you in future

Comment: I fully understood that the issue was with the table cells and not with the checkboxes themselves, I just couldn't figure out how to write a selector that would capture them. I chose to go with the jQuery method you suggested, because of the difficulty of changing style on HTML generated by ASP.Net. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't showing it, but apparently at some point class `.formTable` is being assigned to the CheckBoxList. Just remove `border: solid 1px #bbbbbb;` from the second class declaration:

```
.formTable tr, .formTable tr td, .formTable tr th
{
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 3px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pgpR3/1/

Comment: If I do that, I lose the borders around the table cells, which I want to keep. I think this is happening because ASP.Net renders the CheckBoxList as a table, and for some reason `.formTable` is being applied to the table-within-a-table. And no, I can't change the rendering of the CheckBoxList to Flow, it looks like crap.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove borders around actual check marks?

Comment: No, just around the ASP.Net-generated table cells the checkboxes are in. I'll mock up an image of what I want it to look like and post it to be clear.

Comment: @timbck2 ya, post an image

Comment: Done - I posted three images illustrating what's going on and what I want to achieve.

Comment: @timbck2 it looks like TD border you want to remove. Honestly, i no more understand your issue. Looks here, TDs with borders: http://jsfiddle.net/qSCT5/  And without borders: http://jsfiddle.net/qSCT5/1/   If still not, please provide a jsfiddle by just copying rendered HTML (not ASP code...) and CSS into jsfiddle

Comment: @timbck2 like that: http://jsfiddle.net/ZR2FJ/2/  ???  EDIT: no, this removes border for gender too

Comment: @timbck2 so using more specific selector: http://jsfiddle.net/ZR2FJ/3/  or that using only CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ZR2FJ/5/  `table table td {
    border:none !important;
}`